# Error while making GET request to retrofit api in Android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

When I am making GET request to retrofit it gives me an error **400 - Bad Request**.

> This error is thrown when request length is greater than 1024.

It works fine when request length is less than 1024. I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: is the error code 400? Can you add a logging-interceptor ans post the error log?

Comment: 1024 seems quite short, but there are limits, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: @JacobCelestine, yes error code is 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**
It was not an issue of retrofit. The problem was inside Api(WCF) which I was using. In web config, the value of maxQueryStringLength was set to 1024. I got the exact issue when I sent the request using Postman.